# Unity Interactable = False suddenly not working

Tags: button, unity-game-engine

now i encountered a very very weird issue. below is the code. pardon the length. This class has multiple function that were working when there only 3 (upt to button C)buttons being reference, **in fact the one installed on my phone has the already pressed button disabled after i go back to the initial scene.**

So me thinking all is good decided to do this for all the buttons that I have on my initial Screen. But for some reason it is not working, **it is not disabling the buttons anymore.** I have the GameLogic.cs where i have my variables declared and this script as well. 16 buttons = 16 Alphabets. So basically it just increments a value once button is pressed then once we go back to the initial screen On update, if the value is >= 1 then that particular button must be disabled.

Again it is working when i first built it for the phone. it is there. this is so weird.  Maybe you can see some issue with the code here perhaps?

Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class forButtonDisabler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button buttonA;
    public Button buttonB;
    public Button buttonC;
    public Button buttonD;
    public Button buttonE;
    public Button buttonF;
    public Button buttonG;
    public Button buttonH;
    public Button buttonI;
    public Button buttonJ;
    public Button buttonK;
    public Button buttonL;
    public Button buttonM;
    public Button buttonN;
    public Button buttonO;
    public Button buttonP;


    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Button Events

        buttonA = GameObject.Find("btn5ptsPP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonB = GameObject.Find("btn5ptsDP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonC = GameObject.Find("btn5ptsTE").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonD = GameObject.Find("btn5ptsTA").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonE= GameObject.Find("btn10ptsPP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonF = GameObject.Find("btn10ptsDP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonG = GameObject.Find("btn10ptsTE").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonH = GameObject.Find("btn10ptsTA").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonI = GameObject.Find("btn15ptsPP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonJ = GameObject.Find("btn15ptsDP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonK = GameObject.Find("btn15ptsTE").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonL = GameObject.Find("btn15ptsTA").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonM = GameObject.Find("btn20ptsPP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonN = GameObject.Find("btn20ptsDP").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonO = GameObject.Find("btn20ptsTE").GetComponent<Button>();
        buttonP = GameObject.Find("btn20ptsTA").GetComponent<Button>();

        buttonA.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonA));
        buttonB.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonB));
        buttonC.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonC));
        buttonD.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonD));
        buttonE.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonE));
        buttonF.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonF));
        buttonG.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonG));
        buttonH.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonH));
        buttonI.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonI));
        buttonJ.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonJ));
        buttonK.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonK));
        buttonL.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonL));
        buttonM.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonM));
        buttonN.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonN));
        buttonO.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonO));
        buttonP.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(buttonP));


    }

    private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == buttonA)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn1++;

        }

        if (buttonPressed == buttonB)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn2++;

        }

        if (buttonPressed == buttonC)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn3++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonD)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn4++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonE)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn5++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonF)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn6++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonG)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn7++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonH)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn8++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonI)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn9++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonJ)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn10++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonK)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn11++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonL)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn12++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonM)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn13++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonN)
        {

            GameLogic.Cbtn14++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonO)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn15++;


        }
        if (buttonPressed == buttonP)
        {


            GameLogic.Cbtn16++;


        }

    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register Button Events
        buttonA.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonB.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonC.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonD.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonE.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonF.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonG.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonH.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonI.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonJ.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonK.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonL.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonM.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonN.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonO.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        buttonP.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn1 >= 1)
        {
            buttonA.interactable = false;


        }

        if (GameLogic.Cbtn2 >= 1)
        {

            buttonB.interactable = false;

        }

        if (GameLogic.Cbtn3 >= 1)
        {
            buttonC.interactable = false;


        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn4 >= 1)
        {
            buttonD.interactable = false;


        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn5 >= 1)
        {
            buttonE.interactable = false;


        }

        if (GameLogic.Cbtn6 >= 1)
        {
            buttonF.interactable = false;


        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn7 >= 1)
        {
            buttonG.interactable = false;


        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn8 >= 1)
        {
            buttonH.interactable = false;


        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn9 >= 1)
        {
            buttonI.interactable = false;


        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn10 >= 1)
        {
            buttonJ.interactable = false;


        }

        if (GameLogic.Cbtn11 >= 1)
        {
            buttonK.interactable = false;


        }

        if (GameLogic.Cbtn12 >= 1)
        {
            buttonL.interactable = false;
        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn13 >= 1)
        {
            buttonM.interactable = false;
        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn14 >= 1)
        {
            buttonN.interactable = false;
        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn15 >= 1)
        {
            buttonO.interactable = false;
        }
        if (GameLogic.Cbtn16 >= 1)
        {
            buttonP.interactable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working...What's not working? "Again it is working when i first built it for the phone" Can you explain more? No one knows what problem you are having...

Comment: It is not disabling the buttons anymore for some reason. not sure why. when i was just referencing only 3 buttons it was working. now in the editor it's not disabling the button that i've already used. again this all happened after i added buttons 4 and up.

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` inside your `if (GameLogic.xxx >= 1)` to see what's happening. Maybe, those are never >=1.

Comment: i'll try. i just accidentally deleted my scenes folder. i'm back to square 1. thanks man.

Comment: ok i tried. i think it's one: 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
forButtonDisabler2:Update() (at Assets/forButtonDisabler2.cs:77)

Comment: i also tried changing the cbtn=1 instead of 0 and on run time it is disabled. somewhere somehow it's not working. any thoughts?

Comment: ok i think it worked by defining the functions as public void for some reason. why is that?

Comment: Sorry, really don't know why. It's hard to replicate your problem.